# Using get_posts to retrieve posts found in more than one category (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I've looked for a while but have yet to find a solution that works for this.

I want to be able to use the Wordpress function "get_posts()" to retrieve any posts that belong to two different categories (and by that I mean AND not OR). If I separate by a comma like this:

```
'category'=>'1,2';
```

it appears to retrieve posts belonging to CAT 1 OR CAT 2, as opposed to CAT 1 AND CAT 2. How do I do this with get_posts?

I've seen this as a solution, but it doesn't appear to work for me:

```
'category__and' => array(1,2)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, after trying to implement the solution below, I realized that when trying the 'category__and' solution, the variable I was using for one of the IDs was spelled incorrectly. When I fixed that, it worked. To recap the solution was calling:

`get_posts( array( 'category__and'=>array($id1,$id2) ) )`

Thanks to @seoul for the response. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot do this with `get_posts()` because `get_posts()` will call only 1 query (no subquery) and you need a subquery here to determine which rows to skip depending on desired condition.

You have to follow this code fragment:

```
$desiredCategory = array( 2, 6 );
$finalPostID = array();
$allPosts = get_posts( array('category__and' => $desiredCategory) );

foreach ($allPosts as $postVariable)
{
  $categories = get_the_category($postVariable->ID);
  if( in_array($desiredCategory, $categories) )
    $finalPostID [] = $postVariable;
}

// Now you can use $finalPostID as your collection of posts.
```